# Вычислить корни уравнения ln(x)+x-0.5=0 методом Ньютона с заданной точностью eps

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы

Накидал кода, но правильного ответа нету. Где может быть ошибка?)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double fx, f, fa, x, e;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Веедите x= ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Введите e= ";
    cin >> e;
    cout << endl;
    //x=1;
    //e=0.00001;
    fx = log(x);
    cout << endl << fx;
    while (abs(f) > e)
    {
        f = fx + x - 0.5;
        fa = 1 / x + 1;
        x = x - f / fa;
        cout << "x= " << x << "\n";
    }
    cout << "Конечное решение х= " << x << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: А что с ним работать? Производная от `ln(x)` равна 1/x, вычисляется с помощью функции `log(x)` из `<cmath>`... Что еще нужно?

Comment: я разбирался с этим заданием до того как написал этот пост, пока писал и после того как написал. Просто код был не готовым, точнее он просто ужасным был, я немного подправил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну смотрите сами - вот метод Ньютона:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот производная вашей функции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делим функцию на производную, вычисляем... Принимаем, что когда разность между двумя точками меньше ε - решение найдено. Всё!

```
int main()
{
    const double eps = 1e-8;
    double dx, x = 1.0;  // Начальное приближение
    do
    {
        dx = -x*(log(x)+x-0.5)/(1+x);
        x += dx;
    } while(abs(dx) >= eps);

    cout << x << endl;

}
```

Ваша главная ошибка - вы **НЕ** вычисляете логарифм, а всегда используете его значение в некоторой начальной точке. Т.е. пытаетесь решить уравнение `fx - x = 0.5`, где `fx` - это значение логарифма. Могли бы не мучиться и просто выводить `fx-0.5` :)